# javaws with two different jvm error

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have an app who works in first version with IBM JVM, imb-jre1.5.0, and in the second version with standard oracle jre 1.6

From a computer I need to run two versions, in two different enterprises.

Each version has a different jnlp file:

Version 1 JNLP 1- IBM-JRE1.5.0

```
...
...
<resources>    
<j2se version="1.5.0-ibm" href="file://C:/Archivos de Programa/Java/ibm-jre1.5.0"/> 
...
...
```

Version 2 - Oracle jre 1.6

```
...
...
<resources>
<j2se version="1.6" max-heap-size="1024m"/>
...
...
```

Running Windows XP, I can run both apps whith javaws, first one with the javaws command of ibm-jre1.5.0 and the second one with the javaws command of jre 1.6

Now, I have Windows 7, and when I try to run the first one, I get the next error

```
You can not load the resource: (file://C:/Program Files/Java/ibm-jre1.5.0, 1.5.0-ibm)
JNLPException[category: Download Error: Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: C : LaunchDesc: null ]
    at com.sun.javaws.cache.DownloadProtocol.doDownload(DownloadProtocol.java:686)
    at com.sun.javaws.cache.DownloadProtocol.getJRE(DownloadProtocol.java:745)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadJRE(LaunchDownload.java:579)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.downloadResources(Launcher.java:1080)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.handleApplicationDesc(Launcher.java:424)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.handleLaunchFile(Launcher.java:254)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:201)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:801)
```

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: BTW - I think you'll find that Oracle has disabled any ability to run JWS apps. using an older (than current) JRE.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Already checked with Janela. No warnings about j2se tag. Trying more things... :(

Comment: *"No warnings about j2se tag."*  Fix any other errors that **are** reported.  Once an error is in a JNLP, it is anybody's guess as to how a JWS client will parse or interpret it.

Comment: No warnings at all now with janela, but the same error running it ....  You can not load the resource: (file://C:/Program Files/Java/ibm-jre1.5.0, 1.5.0-ibm)